# How can I make a button redirect my page to another page using addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently after searching the internet I've come up with this code:

```
function button(){


        var button= getElementById("Sailthru");

    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick, false, 0, true)
  function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.sailthru.com/"), "_blank");
};
```

Though it doesn't work, and I am unsure how to proceed. If there are no ways to make it work using this, then I will happily use another method. However I would like to use this  method since I've been working on this for a while.

Answer (score 5):

What language mix is this?

The easiest way to go about this using plain vanilla javascript is something like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById("Sailthru");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.location.href = 'http://www.sailthru.com';
});
```

Comment: I found some of this  from a previous post, and it said something like AS2

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this uses HTTP redirects.

HTML

```
<button id="btn">
  Click
</button>
```

JS

```
btn.onclick = function() {
  window.location.replace("http://www.sailthru.com/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

window.open or window.location based on your demand

window.open('http://test.com','_blank');

window.location="http://test.com";